# IMU (gyro + accelerometer) breakout board with integrated Kalman filtering?

Tags: accelerometer, gyro, imu

I am in need of a reliable gyro/accelerometer combo, that already has built-in motion processing (don't want to deal with Kalman filters in software). It seems that there are breakout boards out there (like IMU Fusion Board – ADXL345 & IMU3000), offering built-in motion processing, but the online comments sections reveal that that is not the case, or that it is rather hard to achieve. The MPU-6050 sounds more reliable, yet there is no official breakout board available yet.

The whole project will consist of ~25 sensors, that will all be connected to a desktop computer. I want to avoid having to do the heavy Kalman filtering for all sensors in software on the computer. Therefore i am looking for a sensor-board that already integrates the filtering.

- DOF: I actually only need 1 DOF as the project has just one rotation point (think of a swing). But all available boards seem to have the maximum DOF.
- Range: >= 150 degree/second
- Frequency Response:  >= 100 Hz
- Noise: I am really hoping for a quite noise-free signal, to avoid heavy interpolation-filters later on (on the desktop computer)
- A plus would be if i could daisy-chain those boards together. If not i'll have to add another hardware piece that chains them together.

Any recommendations or comments would be appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT: 
I found this MPU-6050 breakout board at [drotek.fr](http://www.drotek.fr/shop/en/42-mpu6050-gyro-accelerometer.html), looking for some experience reports now.

EDIT2:
I opted for the [Razor IMU](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736) in the end, even though it was a bit pricey. There is pretty good [firmware](https://dev.qu.tu-berlin.de/projects/sf-razor-9dof-ahrs) around.

Comment: "MotionFusion" is apparently Invensense's name for integrated kalman filtering. As such, it's not a general term in really any sense. I changed your title to reflect this.

Comment: Incidentally, this is kind of a shopping question, which is generally frowned on. However, there are enough non-shopping avenues of inquiry that I'm leaving it as-is.

Comment: Incidentally, have you looked at the SparkFun [Razor IMU](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736)? It seems like it can do what you want, and the software has apparently been updated to work with the last few months.

Comment: thanks for correcting. and yes, it is inherently about shopping, but it would avoid lots of extra how-to questions later on (if i buy the wrong thing) :) Looking at the Razor IMU now. Looks interesting. Maybe a bit above the wished price-range (considering i'll need 25 of them).

Comment: Please add some specs such as the accuracy needed, the frequency response, the maximum computing load that you can have...

Comment: range: >= 150 degree/second, Frequency Response: >= 100 Hz, not sure how to answer the maximum-computing load question.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a project to implement the Kalman filter on an embedded system that was similar in hardware to the [iNemo](http://www.st.com/internet/analog/subclass/1448.jsp) unit from STMicroelectronics.

Even if you can find these IMU (Inertial Measuring Unit) with 90% chance you will have to implement your algorithm by yourself; or if you're lucky, you can find someone that has the code. The problem is that this filter requires a lot of computation, and in our best experiment (using fixed point variables and trying to optimize the code) we were able to run it 45 times per second, in a STM32 at 72 MHz.

So maybe there is one, but as far as I know requires a good microcontroller or maybe a FPGA\ASIC.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Our project would probably work at 45Hz. But we don't have the time to create our own system, so i am hoping to find a rather simple plug+play solution.

Comment: I've seen that OpenCV has a library function for [Kalman filter](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut9.html) but I think that is quite dependent from the application, so good luck to find one :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a Wiimote with the motion plus accessory.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: A Wiimote is a device which includes a IMU. And you can connect to it using bluetooth.

Comment: What ?? It solved the problem...... It's an integrated, off the shelf solution and protocol is well known.

Comment: @Blup1980I think you would get a better response if you were to add more detail. What specs does the WiiMote meet, what are its real specs.